# One expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query is as follows, and contains a subquery within it

```
UPDATE [dbo].[VW_blindLeadTicket] 
SET [ExtendedStatusFK] = 3 
WHERE [LeadTicketPK] IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[VW_blindLeadTicket] 
                         WHERE [BlindLeadTicketStatusName] = N'New' 
                           AND [CreationDate] BETWEEN N'2010-01-01' AND N'2021-03-01' 
                           AND [CompanyFranchiseeName] = N'New Homes')
```

I get this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Comment: WHERE [LeadTicketPK] IN  (..). In subquery you need to have scalar values of LeadTicketPK

Comment: `SELECT *` would return **every** column; define the column you want.

Comment: Little tip by the way: **always** specify the table alias of the columns in subqueries, this prevents ambiguous or mistaken column references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you intend:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[VW_blindLeadTicket]
    SET [ExtendedStatusFK] = 3
    WHERE [LeadTicketPK] IN (SELECT LeadTicketPK
                             FROM [dbo].[VW_blindLeadTicket]
                             WHERE [BlindLeadTicketStatusName] = N'New' AND 
                                   [CreationDate] BETWEEN N'2010-01-01' AND N'2021-03-01' AND
                                   [CompanyFranchiseeName] = N'New Homes'
                            );
```

The problem is the `SELECT *`.  That selects more than one column -- which is what the error indicates.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the `IN` syntax, which @GordonLinoff has kindly fixed for you, **you could also do this as a joined `UPDATE`**, this can often be more readable:

```sql
UPDATE blt1 
SET [ExtendedStatusFK] = 3
FROM [dbo].[VW_blindLeadTicket] blt1
JOIN [dbo].[VW_blindLeadTicket] bt2
    ON blt2.[LeadTicketPK] = blt1.[LeadTicketPK]
WHERE blt2.[BlindLeadTicketStatusName] = N'New' 
  AND blt2.[CreationDate] BETWEEN N'2010-01-01' AND N'2021-03-01' 
  AND blt2.[CompanyFranchiseeName] = N'New Homes'
```

This has the exact same semantic as the `IN` version, and should have the same query plan.

---

Furthermore, this particular query is a self-join, and therefore can also be expressed as **a filter on a window aggregate.** We can place that in a CTE, and update the CTE directly:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(CASE
        WHEN [BlindLeadTicketStatusName] = N'New' 
          AND [CreationDate] BETWEEN N'2010-01-01' AND N'2021-03-01' 
          AND [CompanyFranchiseeName] = N'New Homes'
       THEN 1 END)
      OVER (PARTITION BY [LeadTicketPK]) AS cnt
    FROM [dbo].[VW_blindLeadTicket]
)
UPDATE blt1 
SET [ExtendedStatusFK] = 3
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 0
```

This second option may be more or less efficient, depending on cardinality (number of matching rows) and relevant indexes. You should test both options.

---

One further point: if `CreationDate` is a `datetime` and has a time component then it is much better to use a **half-open interval** `CreationDate >= N'2010-01-01' AND CreationDate < N'2021-03-01'`